# How to get .ipa .aab, zip and tar.gz files from published expo project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, ipa, aabb

I've just started learning expo and react native and I need to get .ipa .aab, zip and tar.gz files for a published project. I've created a build using eas build and expo build:android, then released it on a dev channel using eas submit, but now I need the actual .ipa .aab, zip and tar.gz files, where do I get them from? Any help and advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: go to expo.dev and check in the deployments, for an apk you would need to specify it in the dev channel.

Comment: @Anhishek Sah, thank you. I was able to get .aab and .ipa files, but can't find zip and tar.gz files. Do you know where can I get these from?

Comment: i do not think there are those files.